# Is it possible to have a background image in Napili template community through point and click?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, css, napili, template

I am trying to insert a background image for the entire home page and I need to put a rich text editor component over the image with a welcome message. In branding, I am not able to find an option to put the background image over the entire page.So is this doable using point and click or do I need to use CSS? Also, is the library component available out of the box customizable in terms of applying different font color? I appreciate any insight you can give me on whats ahead of me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use CSS in order to achieve this, more specifically, you might want to create a [custom layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) for your home page if it is the only place where you need the image in full background. As per the components that are available in lightning, none of them are fully customizable, only CSS wise, as soon as you require a slightly different functionality than what the OOTB offers, you need to go custom.

Comment: Thanks for the reply glls. Using the CSS, is it also possible to customize the library component so that it can have different font color, size etc?

Comment: yes, however, note that you will have to manually look for the CSS to scope to, and the components css classes are subject to change in future releaseas which can break your CSS at any time.